# Check for presence of Java function in applet from javascript in IE9

Tags: java, javascript, applet, internet-explorer-9

Hello stackoverflow community,

I have some code that works on virtually every browser except for .... (Wait for it).... IE9 (and possibly other versions of IE?).

So, I've added an applet to the page, everything goes well, but I want to check to see if the applet is loaded, so to do that, I've been polling to see if the functions in the applet exist.

For example, let's say I have this method in my java applet:

```
public int dummy( int a ) {
  return a + 1;
}
```

So in my javascript, I poll to see if the function exists like this (using jquery, where #applet is the id of the applet tag):

```
var japp = $("#applet").get(0);
if( japp && japp.dummy ) {
  alert( japp.dummy(1) );
}
```

You'd notice that this works at least in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE9.

In IE9, regardless of the method being accessible, `japp.dummy` always returns `undefined`

Does anyone know a good IE9 workaround?

Thanks,
-Oz

Comment: I'm not against doing that, but I'm sort of curious why IE9 fails here where other browsers don't.

Comment: Okay, I guess that's something I have to accept.  If you could add that as an answer I can vote it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to check to see if the applet is loaded, so to do that, I've been polling to see if the functions in the applet exist.

Don't do that. Instead, have the applet call a JS function at the end of `init()`. The end of `init()` is when the applet is ready.

> IE9 fails here where other browsers don't.

Substitute IE9 with 'any browser' and you have the niggling problems with applet/JRE/JS/browser interaction pegged. That's the nature of applets, unfortunately.  :(

Answer (score 4):

Try it in this way:

```
<object id="idOfMyApplet" ... >
    <param> ... </param>
</object>


function testApplet() {
    var myApplet = document.applets.idOfMyApplet;
    if (!myApplet) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        myApplet.publicTestMethod();
    } catch(ex) { 
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var retryCounter = 20;
var appletLoaded = false;

function waitForApplet() {
    if (!testApplet()) {
        if (retryCounter > 0) {
            retryCounter--;
            setTimeout("waitForApplet()", 500);
        }
        return false;
    }
    appletLoaded = true;
    return true;
}
```